# After migrating the WP site to AWS, there are issues in styling

Tags: wordpress

I would really glad that if you can help this.

We have created WP site locally (using windows 10 PC) and migrated to AWS (Ubuntu Server), Then found styles are not aligned as original local site.

As a workaround we have done following steps

1- provided access to folders as 777, 775, etc,,

2- Clear server cache

3- Plugins deactivated & reactivated.

But all theses steps did not success.

when we check the WP-Admin panel following error message is displayed.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ER852.jpg)

If you need further information please let us know

Thank you very much
NexTeam

Comment: can you show website console error from inspect element.

Comment: Hi Aviboy, Thank for your concerns, please find below console error ..................................GET http://13.235.85.181/nexlms/wp-content/uploads/tc_stylesheets/eduma.1593497347.css?ver=5.4.2 net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Comment: check ur wp-content/uploads/ has right permission or not. also check ownership also.

Comment: Hi Aviboy, thank you for comment, we have already set for full access (like 777) still it has same issue.